# Building a chord diagram with Holoviews: no error, but no image saved either

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh, holoviews, chord-diagram

I want to draw a chord diagram. To first get the method working, I was following [this](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/route_chord.html#bokeh-gallery-route-chord) example. (Note that for this, on the command line, you have to type 'bokeh sampledata' to download the sample data).

The code I used (taken mostly from the example, but adding in matplotlib to save the image) is:

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts, dim
from bokeh.sampledata.airport_routes import routes, airports
hv.extension('bokeh')

# Count the routes between Airports
route_counts = routes.groupby(['SourceID', 'DestinationID']).Stops.count().reset_index()
nodes = hv.Dataset(airports, 'AirportID', 'City')
chord = hv.Chord((route_counts, nodes), ['SourceID', 'DestinationID'], ['Stops'])

# Select the 20 busiest airports
busiest = list(routes.groupby('SourceID').count().sort_values('Stops').iloc[-20:].index.values)
busiest_airports = chord.select(AirportID=busiest, selection_mode='nodes')

fig = plt.figure()
busiest_airports.opts(opts.Chord(cmap='Category20', edge_color=dim('SourceID').str(),height=800, labels='City', node_color=dim('AirportID').str(), width=800))
fig.savefig('plot.png')
```

There is a file called plot.png made, but it is empty. I've tried editing the code slightly in different ways (e.g. doing different image formats such as .pdf) but it doesn't change. Does anyone have any ideas?

Update to what works:
    import holoviews as hv
    from holoviews import opts, dim
    from bokeh.sampledata.airport_routes import routes, airports
    hv.extension('bokeh')

```
# Count the routes between Airports
route_counts = routes.groupby(['SourceID', 'DestinationID']).Stops.count().reset_index()
nodes = hv.Dataset(airports, 'AirportID', 'City')
chord = hv.Chord((route_counts, nodes), ['SourceID', 'DestinationID'], ['Stops'])

# Select the 20 busiest airports
busiest = list(routes.groupby('SourceID').count().sort_values('Stops').iloc[-20:].index.values)
busiest_airports = chord.select(AirportID=busiest, selection_mode='nodes')
plot = busiest_airports.opts(opts.Chord(cmap='Category20', edge_color=dim('SourceID').str(),height=800, labels='City', node_color=dim('AirportID').str(), width=800))
hv.save(plot,'plot2.png')
```

and it works, as suggested below.

Comment: Is there any indication that you can mix holoviews bokeh with matplotlib? That is, how is the matplotlib figure `fig` supposed to know it should contain any data?

Comment: Wow I literally just assumed. Thanks so much, have just found this: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Matplotlib.html and am giving it a go now.

Comment: Anything to do with matplotlib should be able to be deleted in the above code; that code is not doing anything, because you selected the bokeh extension, not matplotlib.  You also shouldn't need both hv.output and hv.save; hv.save should be sufficient.